# How do I calculate the median values for a year from a 29 years dataset both on hourly basis?

Tags: sorting, datetime, time-series, median, hour

From a longterm dataset on hourly basis, I want to have median values for each hour of 1 representative year. For example: The median value of the first hour from January the 1st for the representative year is calculated from January the 1st from every year in the dataset. The dataset is available here:https://github.com/sugarello/sugarello/blob/master/dfsolarbwdlz.csv

After trying rolling() and groupby(), I ended up creating new data frames by defining criteria for the index.
So far I tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt




dfsolar = pd.read_csv('dfsolarbwdlz.csv', delimiter=';')
dfsolar['MESS_DATUM'] = pd.to_datetime(dfsolar['MESS_DATUM'], format='%Y%m%d%H')
dfsolar.set_index('MESS_DATUM')
dfsolar.index = dfsolar['MESS_DATUM']
dfsolarr = dfsolar.drop(columns=["MESS_DATUM"])
```

By defining criteria for month, day and hour I partially receive the data I am looking for. It is not practical though at all cause I have to repeat it 8760 times. For example only for the 13.th hour of January 1st:

```
dfsolarWI00 = dfsolarr[((dfsolarr.index.month == 1) & (dfsolarr.index.day == 1) & (dfsolarr.index.hour == 13))]
```

The output of my last attempt looks like: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM9Xb.png)

I assume one solution within sort_index()/sort(). However I wasnt able to set up an adequate searching algorithm.
Am I on the right track? What is an elegant solution for my problem?

Comment: Or should I use an index-based querying? Id be very happy to get any kind of advice.

Answer (score 0):

After looking deeper into the conditions of the groupby-Method, I reordered as follows:

```
dfsolarrtest = dfsolarr.groupby([dfsolarr.index.month, dfsolarr.index.day, dfsolarr.index.hour]).median()

 dfsolarrtest.plot(figsize=(80,40))
```

and produced the following plot:[image]

If I am not mistaken, I found my solution by reordering the groupby-conditions based on the changing parts of the date of my given format. However:
I generated a dataset consisting of 8784 rows which definitely does not equal to 8760 hours. Also, single median values by:

```
median_example = dfsolarr[((dfsolar.index.month == 1) & (dfsolarr.index.hour == 16))]

median_example.median()
```

Are not equal to the exact same date from the calculated dataset with groupby.
Any help?